# How to switch design for each cards in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

How to switch between different card designs for each data in the for loop.

```
<div class="col-1-of-3">
    <div class="card">
     ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-1-of-3">
    <div class="card">
     ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-1-of-3">
    <div class="card">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

These three cards have different designs, Currently facing trouble in switching these cards for each loop in the Django template.

```
{% for cont in data %}
   {% ifequal forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" True %}

    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        <div class="card">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>

   {% endifequal %}

   {% ifequal forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" True %}

    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        <div class="card">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>

   {% endifequal %}

   {% ifnotequal forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" True %}

    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        <div class="card">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>

   {% endifnotequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Third card logic is wrong. I need to change this logic so that for each loop each cards need to be displayed alternatively. And another challenge is that after 3 loop  it should close the section, since in a row only 3 cards are allowed.

```
<section class="section-tours" id="section-tours">

            {% ifequal forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" True %}
            {% endifequal %}

            {% ifequal forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" True %}
            {% endifequal %}

            {% ifequal forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" True %}
            {% endifequal %}

</section>
```

Comment: How many records do you have in your data which you are trying to iterate? Moreover you are trying to separate the cards by divisibility of 2 and 3, there numbers which are divisible by both 2 and 3 like 6,12 so on..and that is not very efficient

Comment: The cards lists all the books available in library, the content is dynamic it may be added in dashboard. What should be done to iterate within three cards, I know the logic in the above program is not correct.

Comment: Is there any Django template filter for getting reminder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section is closed after printing 3 cards.

```
<section class='section-tours' id='section-tours'>
  <div class="row">
{% for cont in data %}

    {% cycle 'tools/col-1-of-3.html' 'tools/col-2-of-3.html' 'tools/col-3-of-3.html' as tmp silent %}
    {% include tmp %}

    {% cycle "" "" "</div> </section><section class='section-tours' id='section-tours'>" %}

{% endfor %}
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use build in django [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) template tag for this. You can update your html and add the cycle template tag like below to change design of 1st, 2nd and 3rd card.

```
{% for cont in data %}
    <div class="{% cycle 'col-1-of-3' 'col-2-of-3' 'col-3-of-3' %}">
        <div class="card">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: 3 cards of different styles, how this will select one of 3 different cards alternatively and close the <section> </section> tag after printing 3 cards. There are lots of cards available on database, so for printing different designs in a row we need to select different cards on each loop.The three cards printed should be in <section> tag, in-order to make a new row.

Comment: 3 cards of three different style. In this case cycle tag will help you for adding a css class for 3 cards. In first iteration it will add first, on second it will add second and so on. You have to apply different logic for opening and closing section tag. Update your question and add accurate information with desire result so one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Test the below code and tell me if it helps, since I have not tested it.

I have sliced the for loop for first three values, if you want to repeat the same change the slice for same code.

```
{% for cont in data|slice:":3" %} #i have sliced it for first three values only
   {% if forloop.first %}

    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        <div class="card">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>

   {% endif %}

   {% ifequal forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" True %}

    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        <div class="card">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>

   {% endifequal %}

   {% if forloop.last %}

    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        <div class="card">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>

   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Only first three cards are visible other data are not showing up in the cards. And the <section> is not implemented.